# Windows 10 Mail swipe actions stopped working

Tags: windows-10, email, touchscreen, gestures

I was using the touch "swipe actions" in Windows Mail to archive individual emails.

For some reason, the swipe actions seem to be gone. Now when I swipe an email with my finger, it acts like a "drag" action, and thinks I want to drag the email somewhere.

What is going on? Quick actions are still configured correctly in settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the touchscreen was acting like a mouse. It appears that an eGalax driver update caused this (from windows update automatically).

The solution is to find the "USB Touchscreen Controller" in Device Manager, and Rollback the driver.

After that the touchscreen worked like, well, a touchscreen.